# memcached issue on multi-core windows server with virtualization

Tags: performance, virtualization, windows-server-2008-r2, cache, multi-core

i am having an issue running memcached (v1.4.4) on multiple cores. Here's my environment:

Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 running VMware, Intel Processor, only one core (out of eight) is enabled for the project that i am working on.

on the resource monitor, i can observe between eight and nine threads of memcached running at any given moment, even though the registry entry is not configured with the (-t) flag, so i would have expected the number of threads to be between four and five. (four is default, and as it turns out, it is not uncommon for memcached to run one additional thread than indicated)

also, this version of memcached is running from a downloaded executable; it has not been compiled on the local windows server. this (http://trondn.blogspot.com/2010/03/building-memcached-windows.html) is the only resource i have found on compiling memcached on windows, in case someone recommends going that route.

the issue appears when enabling another core from the VM, memcached starts consuming 100% of the cpu; we have to disable the new core to go to a normal state from a performance standpoint. (note: i do not have any details on how this was done, so if the solution proves to be a graceful exit and restart, i would welcome more details) also, this is a production environment, so the server cannot be down for an extended period of time.

i would welcome any ideas or suggestions

Comment: What version of Windows server?  Is it an AMD or Intel processor?

Comment: windows server 2008 R2 (SP1) + intel processor